# Create login page using Javabeans (properties not being set)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, javabeans

Okay, so I am trying to create a login page for a website I am working on. I am using Javabeans in eclipse. I have my bean set up, but the property are not being set.

Here is the code for my login.jsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log-In</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html">
    </head>

    <body>

    <jsp:useBean id="login" class="edu.iup.COSC473.Beans.LoginBean" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="login" property="*"/>

    <form method="post" action="check.jsp">

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"/></td>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for check.jsp (a test page I am using to see is the properties are being set):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log-In</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html">
    </head>

    <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="login" class="edu.iup.COSC473.Beans.LoginBean" scope="session"/>
        User Name: <jsp:getProperty name="login" property="username" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is the LoginBean.java class:

```
public class LoginBean {
    String username;
    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why my properties are not being set when I click the submit button on the login page. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the setProperty tag in your check.jsp because parameters are submitted to this page and will be set in bean in this page only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, I tried that and got that to work. However I am not running into a different issue. I am trying to take the information from the bean and pass it into another class to check against a database of usernames and passwords. Another nullpointerexception is appearing. Here is my code for that:

My class LoginBean

```
package edu.iup.COSC473.Beans;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import edu.iup.COSC473.DAO.LoginDAO;

public class LoginBean {
    String username;
    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String processSubmit() throws SQLException {
            String checkPassword = LoginDAO.selectPasswordByUsername(username);

            if (checkPassword != null && checkPassword.equals(password)) {
                return "correct";
            } else {
                return "incorrect";
            }
    }

}
```

My class LoginDAO

```
public class LoginDAO {

    public static Connection conn;

    public LoginDAO(Connection conn) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        super();
        conn = DatabaseConnection.connect();
    }

    public static String selectPasswordByUsername(String userId)
            throws SQLException {
        String password = null;

        PreparedStatement selectUser = conn.prepareStatement("select password"
                + "from Client " + "where ClientID = ?");

        selectUser.setString(1, userId);

        ResultSet rsUser = selectUser.executeQuery();

        if (rsUser.next()) {
            password = rsUser.getString(1);
        }

        return password;

    }
}
```

My Database

```
package edu.iup.COSC473.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    //Change this path when database is moved
    private static String path = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Jayde Ferney/My Documents/Startup Database" ;

    /**
     * This method returns a Connection object that is connected to an SQL database.
     * 
     * @return SQLite database connection
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static Connection connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!